# How to move an object relative to the screen size in animation using Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have animation for object. This object must move for Screen.width/3 to left or right from start position. It should work on different Screen resolutions (for example 1280x720 and 1920*1080, etc). Can anybody help to resolve this problem?

Comment: Kindly share your animation code for people to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a question here?
But are you asking how to smoothly move the object?

If so take a look at this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Or this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

And if you want it as a video tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/translate-and-rotate?playlist=17117

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Unity - Scripting API: Screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html). You have `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`. Then you can do something like

```
object.positionX += Screen.width / 3
object.positionY += Screen.height / 3
```

but that would move the object instantly. Instead you want something like

```
steps = 1000
posXDiff = (Screen.width / 3 - object.positionX) / steps
posYDiff = (Screen.height / 3 - object.positionY) / steps
for i in range(0, steps) do
    object.positionX += posXDiff
    object.positionY += posYDiff
```

By that it will make 1000 steps, each time move a bit. You can have more or less steps, depending on what you want. Keep in mind that `steps = FPS * seconds`.

Comment: I must move object at Animation

Comment: I edited the file answer. I hope I understood correctly that you want the object to be animated.

Comment: Move object at Animation? This doesn't make sense. If you need to move object depending on the screen size, you have to move it from code.